# validate dots and comma with regex ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, activerecord, validation

I have this regex in my model post:

```
validates_format_of :description, :username, :with => /^(?:[^\W_]|\s)*$/u, :message => "should only contain letters, numbers, or .,-_@"
```

But this regex does not allow dots "**.**" and commas "**,**".

**I want allow add this characters to this regex.**

How can I allow that this regex works fine for fields like **username** or textareas for validate letters, numbers, commas, dots...etc

Comment: Note that in Ruby, `^` and `$` mean "start of line" and "end of line" rather than "start of string" and "end of string"; so your regex actually matches any string that contains *at least one line* with only letters and numbers and whitespace.

Comment: What @ruakh says is important, you'll want to use `\A` and `\Z` to anchor to the beginning and end of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
validates_format_of :description, :username, :with => /^(?:[^\W_]|\s|[\.,_@])*$/u, :message => "should only contain letters, numbers, or .,-_@"
```

Comment: Note that this regex can be simplified significantly: it's equivalent to `/^[\w\s.,@]*$/u`.

Comment: And it should be anchored with `\A` and `\z`.